# window.open not working ios 10

Tags: html, ios

I have developed a mobile html webapp that runs on chrome and safari.  It seems that ios 10 update has caused my webapp not to be able to launch url using window.open.  essentially the webapp collects the information and then i use window.open to leave the webapp and open a new tab in which the form has been updated with the information collected.  but as i try to launch url i get the error message webapp failed to open, cannot connect to server.  If i run the app in the browser (so not in fullscreen _meaning setting to homescreen) it will work, it seems as soon as i launched the homescreen icon i get this error. plase any suggections

```
function launchurl(x){
aKS = window.open(unescape(x), 'cwo', '');
}
launchurl("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/jjjjjjHtw7GM31QSgJ1kj0c7Gk/viewform?entry.1583361440=" + textvalue1 + "&entry.1582110718=" + textvalue2 + "&entry.581477285=" + textvalue3 + "&entry.414420907=" + textvalue4 + "&entry.886009407=" + textvalue5 +"&entry.2012346668=" + textvalue7 + "&entry.1997554716=" + textvalue8 + "&entry.11139272="+ textvalue9 +"&entry.1861391454=" + textvalue10 +"&entry.145797294=" + textvalue15+"&entry.744028611=" + textvalue11)}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].